# Sewable LED Ribbon - 1m, 50 LEDs (Blue)

Tags: led

I am looking to integrate these sewable LED ribbons into a project.

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14138

I am wondering how it is possible to power 50 Blue LEDS in series with only 2x 3V coincell batteries or minimum 4.5V as specified on the description.

From what I know, Blue LEDS have quite a large voltage drop. If this is added across all the LEDS in series, 6V should not be enough...I also do not have a specification on the resistors included

Can anyone explain how these work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can. If you look at the [sparkfun video on that page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2o_qzmr8II), they use 2 cr2032 3v batteries directly.**. That's what they intended.

They also show the [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/home_page_posts/2/4/2/3/LED_Fabric_MX01_Series.pdf), where the strip is just leds in parallel and the wire.

It works without a resistor because the wire is thin, the current is low, and the voltage is close to what the leds want. Additionally, coin cells have a high Equivalent series resistance, so they act like a resistor. The higher the load, the more they resist so the lower the voltage and current goes through it. **I would not connect this to a 5v usb power bank without current limiting.** The 4.5V is really the absolute maximum voltage, not the intended actual voltage.

**That said**, coin cell batteries are not ideal. They have a low capacity and the capacity depends on how hard you drive the load. They won't last too long before the leds are very dim. Less than a day, maybe a few hours. The more leds you use, the worse the problem gets.

Comment: I have no frigging idea why this answer is downvoted. The answer by @Misunderstood completely misses the whole point of the question: OP wonders how 50 LEDs _in series_ can be powered by 6 volts. This answer explains by a link to the datasheet that they are _not_ in series.

Comment: Given how grossly overloaded the CR2032 cells will be with 50 LEDs, I wouldn't expect to get more than a few minutes out of them.

Comment: Thanks very much @Passerby, Confirming they are in parallel clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> how it is possible to power 50 Blue LEDS in series with only 2x 3V
>   coincell batteries

The LEDs are connected in parallel (not series) so the voltage required is the same regardless how many LEDs.  If they were wired in series then the voltage required would increase with each additional LED in the string.

---

> or **minimum** 4.5V as specified on the description.

The 4.5V, is not specified as minimum, nor maximum, most likely a nominal voltage.  In the video she showed one 3V cell worked and showed two cells (6V) were brighter.  So 6V worked fine as did 3V.

[image]

---

**The CR2032 discharge curve is relatively flat over its life span which makes it an viable choice for powering LEDs.**

[image]
Source: [CR2032 datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2032.pdf)

**This contrasts with AA Alkaline which has a much steeper discharge curve it life span.**

[image]
Source: [AA Alkaline datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/e91.pdf)

---

This means a 5V USB power pack is a valid choice to power these strings of LEDs.  The draw back to a battery pack is the larger size but that may not be an issue.

Most LEDs are specified at a "test current" which is generally half its max current and are wired in series.  When an LED datasheet specifies a battery voltage rather than current, and they are wired in parallel with the battery, that means the LED is voltage driven and has a built in resistance.

Now the maximum current is specified as <250 mA/m.  The odd thing about this is the spec is for both 25 (4 cm pitch) and 50 (2 cm pitch) LED strings.  I believe the max current is more of a guideline than a specification.  It makes zero sense that a red and green LED could be powered with the same voltage if there was not built in resistance. If a red LED were directly wired to 6V (exceeding the forward voltage (Vf) by 3X) without a current limiting resistance, it would blow. The actual current draw at 4.5V is more like 1 mA each, much less than 250 mA maximum.

As an example of current LED brightness this photo is 3 deep blue LEDs driven at only 10 mA.

[image]

---

The internal resistance (≈10 Ω) of the button cell will have no current limiting ability because it is connected in parallel with the LEDs, not series. And the battery voltage change based on the time and the current being drawn (or capacity).  The battery voltage does not change based on current and internal resistance. See white paper below for further explanation.

Blue, Green, and White typically need about 3V and the others 2V.
These LEDs are voltage driven LEDs that have a resistor built-in to limit the current.
The resistor value for each LED is based on the Vf and possibly the brightness of each LED.
That is, Blue, Green, and White will have a lower resistance than the others.  Green may have the lowest resistance as green usually has the highest Vf.  But green usually has the greatest brightness per mA, so would work well with the same resistance as blue and white. The resistance values used were likely chosen using 4.5V or 5V as the supply voltage.

There are probably better batteries to use than a couple of button cells but will not be easily concealed if used in clothing.  If concealment is not an issue then a 3.6V Li-ion battery would be the best battery because its voltage is right and holds more energy per volume than most batteries.

If used for clothing the button cells will not last long but that is not likely to be an issue as you would probably wear it once and never again (except for Halloween costumes). If you wear these LEDs in public many will comment they are cool but I have no doubt you will also be ridiculed (except on Halloween).

---

> Additionally, coin cells have a high Equivalent series resistance, so
>   they act like a resistor. The higher the load, the more they resist so 
>   the lower the voltage and current goes through it.  --passerby

There is a common myth about CR2032 button cells that due to their internal resistance and low capacity the current is limited to 15 mA and exceeding 15 m
A will damage the battery.  The myth is that the internal resistance increases with current draw.

Mathias Jensen, at Texas Instruments wrote a paper, [*Coin cells and peak current draw*](http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/swra349/swra349.pdf).  In this paper the myth is busted.

In both  the two graphs below the internal resistance starts out at 10 Ω.
This shows the IR is capacity related, not instantaneous current.
NOTE: *this is true for CR2032 and does not apply to lead acid and Li-ion.*

[image]

---

**This graph shows the internal resistance (blue) against a constant 181 mA load (red).**

[image]

---

Notice below the green plot is Internal Resistance. It remains the same even though the drain of the red and blue plots are different.

[image]

Comment: I think some folks will find use for these in both club clothing and fashion shows, even outside costume use.  My city has already had at least one LED and electroluminescent themed fashion show.

Comment: @KH does your comment imply that if you walk down the streets of NYC you will not hear rude comments?  Those naw yorker's are very rude.

Comment: Ohnonononono.  Still potential for criticism as day to day wear in most regions, but wearables are not yet practicable.  Just pointing out a few applications that would produce little criticism though.  My ex-fiance is a seamstress and I followed her progress through fashion school so I've had some passing interest in LED applications in clothing.  I think once durability and washability are achieved we might see some mainstream solutions.

Comment: OP is confused about LEDs in series and parallel and you flood with a lecture in semiconductor physics without answering the actual question.

Comment: @pipe Good point.  I completely missed the series HOW. I interpreted it more like how CAN they be powered with 6V when the minimum voltage is 4.5V.  Thank you.  Physics?   Much of my answer was countering all the technical errors in the other two answers.  The deleted answer recommended AA alkaline. The thing about the wire and battery ESR [sic] and the myth about CR2032 batteries.  If you search "fariy lights resistor" (what these type of LEDs are called), you will find links to this site. The linked to Q & A are erroneous and that bugs me. These are VOLTAGE driven LEDs w/resitors.

Comment: @Misunderstood Yes, the rant about semiconductor physics was mostly hyperbole. I like hyperbole. :)

Comment: @pipe True story.  I am currently being sued for hyperbole.  And my daughter graduated from Harvard Law.